# Book about people who find sleep to be a foreign concept and are scared to sleep?

Tags: story-identification, books

What was that book where a certain advanced civilization of people find sleeping to be a very strange/unusual phenomena and are scared to sleep? Or they mistake sleep for death?

These people looked human but sleep is a foreign concept to them. Maybe they are immune to sleep until somebody succumbed to it, and so struggle to understand it. It felt like it was in the future and an alternate history to the human species.

I'm not sure if it’s sci-fi or fantasy.

I heard about this book around 2007, so it's got to be from before then.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  There aren't a lot of details here; do you remember when you read this?  Was it the entire civilization or just certain people?  Was there anything else going on in this book?  (It seems thin for the plot of an entire book; maybe it was a short story?)

Comment: Welcome Sock (etc.) Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance to our ways. You'll need to take a look at our [story ID checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see what you can jog from your memory, details like the date it was written (or when you read it), what language it was written in, was it a short story collection etc. and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: @DavidW : Alas, it's all I have to go off of - this was a book that seemed scifi and was mentioned to me around 14 years ago when I was in college.

I remember being very intrigued by the plot/setting - that sleep was a strange phenomena and something they had a strong inhibition for and were avoidant of. Otherwise these people looked human. Maybe they are immune to sleep until somebody succumbed to it? It felt like it was in the future and an alternate history to the human species?

Would appreciate any alternate suggestions you might have for me to follow up on.

Comment: I remember reading a story where people were scared to sleep as they believed that their current self would die, and a different person wake up in their place.

Comment: @SimonRichter : Any idea what that story you read was called where they believed sleep would replace their former self? Sounds very intriguing and I wanted to look it up if possible...

Comment: @Sock_Monkey, I'll try to find it again when I get home.

Comment: @SimonRichter Are you thinking of [*Existential Comics*: The Monster](https://existentialcomics.com/comic/1)?

Comment: @DavidW, I remember reading that one as well, so I might be conflating it with another story -- but I'm fairly certain that in the story the entire society shared that conviction, which had interesting legal implications.

Comment: @SimonRichter - were you able to find out at all? It might be close to what I'm having in mind about the societal/legal consequences of sleep in your book

Answer (score 15):

Possibly [Beggars in Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beggars_in_Spain) by [Nancy Kress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_Kress).

From Wikipedia:

> Beggars in Spain and its sequels take place in a future where genetic
> engineering has become a reality, and society and culture face the
> consequences of genetic modifications (genemods), particularly in the
> United States. The story revolves around the existence of the
> "Sleepless": individuals genetically modified to not need sleep, who
> have greater potential for intelligence and accomplishment than
> ordinary humans, called "Sleepers".

Comment: I specifically remember a scene where a group of Sleepless get together and one or more of them take a drug to specifically make them sleep, and the narrator is weirded out by watching it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to take a slightly contrarian view because the description struck a chord with me. The *cheela* of [Dragon's Egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Egg) by [Robert L. Forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_L._Forward) have a similar *mass* to humans, but they are much, much smaller—because they live on a neutron star.

Cheela don't sleep routinely, and the concept of sleep has been forgotten, when under extreme stress, one did enter it:

> Swift-Killer had never hurt so. Her last thought was that Bright had decided to punish her for having the temerity to attempt to talk to God. The automatic protective mechanisms in her body, activated by the lack of body reserves and the shock from the topside burns, suddenly took over. The animal reflexes were turned off, and for the first time in untold generations, a cheela went to sleep.

Sleep turns out to have some benefits, and later in the book some cheela attempt to deliberately induce sleep through physical trauma that is not always successful in its intent.

Answer (score 3):

My first though on seeing the title was "Hostess" (a short story) by Asimov, but it doesn't quite match. I'm submitting this answer, because there is a possibility it is the correct story. It features aliens who are distressed by the human need to sleep (match), but the aliens are not human shape (not a match).

For the aliens, what humans call 'sleep' is indicative of a parasite, which drives the host insane (I think - it's been a while since I read it).

> The name of the story has a double meaning - both "The person who hosts a guest or party" and "one infected by a parasite". Humans don't go insane, since they have "always" had the parasite, and so don't change when infected, like other races do.